# Bind database column value with hiddenfield in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My database column value don't bind with Hiddenfield :

### ASPX Code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/home/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Letter_LetterData.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataManagement_Letter_LetterData" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ResultLabel.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ResultLabel" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Clear() {
            location.reload(true);

        }

        function GetConfrim() {
            if (confirm("Are You Sure ?")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function isNumberKey_txtBoxApplicantContactNo(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 43) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function isNumberKey_txtBoxApplicantCNIC(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 45) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="ajax-loading">
                <div></div>
            </div>

        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <center> 
                      <asp:Panel ID="ResultPanel" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>
                  </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-header bg-primary">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Create Letter</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                        <%--Row_1 Start   --%>  

                                   <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnFieldRecievedLetterID" runat="server" />  

                                  <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                               Letter NO.
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnLetterNumber" Value='<%#Eval("Letter_No") %>' runat="server" />
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxLetterNo" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                               Subject
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnfldltrSubject" Value='<%#Eval("Subject_ltr") %>' runat="server" />
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtltrSubject" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                     <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Sender Designation</label>
                                     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDesignation" CssClass="form-control form-white "></asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnReceivedByDesignation" Value='<%#Eval("SenderDesignation_ID") %>' runat="server" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                      <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">City</label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCity" CssClass="form-control form-white"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                 <%--Row_1 End--%>

                                 <%-- Row_2 Start--%> 
                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Department</label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDepartment" CssClass="form-control form-white "></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                     <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                               Issue Date
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnIssueDate" runat="server" />
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtIssueDate" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="cal1" runat="server" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtIssueDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>


                                        </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                               Recieved Date
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnRecievedDate" runat="server" />
                                            </label>
                                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRecievedDate" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="Cal2" runat="server" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtRecievedDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                     <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Priority ID</label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPriority" CssClass="form-control form-white"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                <%--Row_2 End--%>

                                <%--  Row_3 Start--%> 
                                   <div class="col-md-12">

                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                               Priortized Time/Date
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnPriortizedDateTime" runat="server" />
                                            </label> 
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPriortizedDateTime" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="Cal3" runat="server" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtPriortizedDateTime"></asp:CalendarExtender>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnReceivedByName" Value='<%#Eval("User_ID") %>'  runat="server" />
                                     <%--   <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">User Name</label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUserName" CssClass="form-control form-white "></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>--%>

                                         <div class="col-md-3">
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                               Sender Name
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSenderName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Letter Type</label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLetterType" CssClass="form-control form-white"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                <%--Row_3 End--%>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="Clear()" class="btn btn-success" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" ValidationGroup="ValGroupApplicants" runat="server" 
                                        CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"   />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                                        Text="Update" Visible="false" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel fadeIn">
                            <div class="panel-header bg-success">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Letter Details</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-content">


                                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtSearch" PlaceHolder="Letter Subject"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch"  CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Search" ValidationGroup="S" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div style="overflow-x:auto;width:970px">     <%--This <Div> is used for Horizontel scrolling of GridView--%>
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdview" OnRowCommand="grdview_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="ReceivedLetter_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                     CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive scrollable" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CC99">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Letter_No" HeaderText="Letter Number" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject_ltr" HeaderText="Subject" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SenderDesignation_ID" HeaderText="Sender Designation" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="City_ID" HeaderText="City" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department_ID" HeaderText="Department ID" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="IssueDate" HeaderText="Issue Date" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Received_Date" HeaderText="Received Date" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority_ID" HeaderText="Priority ID" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PrioritizedDatetime" HeaderText="Prioritized Datetime" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_ID" HeaderText="User ID" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sender_Name" HeaderText="Sender Name" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LetterType_ID" HeaderText="LetterType ID" />
                                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdEdit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/Edit1.jpg" HeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />
                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Move Letter"   >
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                   <a href ='<%#"Letter_Movement.aspx?ReceivedLetterId="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ReceivedLetter_ID") + "&LetterNumber=" +HdnLetterNumber.Value + "&LetterSubject=" +HdnfldltrSubject.Value + "&ReceivedByName=" +HdnReceivedByName.Value + "&ReceivedByDesignation=" +HdnReceivedByDesignation.Value %>'>  <img src="../assets/global/images/shopping/Move.png" alt="Ltter Move" style="height:50px;width:50px;" /> </a>
                                  </ItemTemplate>
                                  </asp:TemplateField>
                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/Delete_.jpg" CommandName="cmdDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you Sure ?');" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" />
                                      </ItemTemplate>
                                  </asp:TemplateField>

                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Note : Here only the "ReceivedLetter_ID" is bind while all the remaining column values don't bind with hiddenfield,
i am will be very thankfull to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Content>
 <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAsyncUpload" EventName="Click" />
         <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

- Use Trigger like this.Create a New Button and assign ControlID of "AsyncPostBackTrigger"

Comment: Sir ! Because here i use an anchor tag , through which i pass all the values , how can i use the button through which i could pass all these values.